# Send get request in kotlin (Android )

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to send http get request in andoid app.

```
...
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL

...

fun sendGet(view: View) {
        val url = URL("http://www.google.com/")

        with(url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection) {
            requestMethod = "GET"  // optional default is GET

            println("\nSent 'GET' request to URL : $url; Response Code : $responseCode")

            inputStream.bufferedReader().use {
                it.lines().forEach { line ->
                    println(line)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
```

Then i press send request button app crashes.

Logs

2020-06-08 13:37:58.832 7039-7039/com.example.remote E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.remote, PID: 7039
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7357)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7334)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:808)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28200)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7357) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7334) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:808) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28200) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to www.google.com not permitted
        at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler$CleartextURLFilter.checkURLPermitted(HttpHandler.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:462)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)
        at com.example.remote.MainActivity.sendGet(MainActivity.kt:24)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7357) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7334) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:808) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28200) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)

Comment: Can you also edit the question with Logs shown in Logcat which tells the reason of the crash.

Comment: Check this [How to fix 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/7666442)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This,

```
fun sendGet() {
        try {
            //disable the strict mode otherwise perform this operation on netWork Thread
            val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)

            // GET Request
            val request = "http://www.google.com/"
            val url = URL(request)
            val conn = url.openConnection()
            conn.doOutput = true
            // Get the response
            val rd = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))
            var line: String
            var sResult = ""
            while (rd.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                // Process line...
                sResult = "$sResult$line "
            }
            rd.close()
            Log.e("RESULT", sResult)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Error $e")
        }
    }
```

Comment: 2020-06-08 21:20:03.696 16271-16271/com.example.remote I/System.out: Error java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.google.com/

Comment: Paste your GET request URL properly instead of google.com

Comment: Thanks. I ve tried to send a request to iplogger.  It is working !

Comment: LOVE YOU! You have made my day)

Comment: you're welcome. Please, also do upvote.. if you're problem has been solved.